# SQL:How to select column that last 3 digit are multiply of 4?

Tags: sql, database

My *sql* schema is like this : [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5989)

I want to Show the TransactionID, DoctorID, PatientID, and TotalMedicine (obtained from amount  of MedicineID on each transaction) where the last 3 digits numbers of PatientID are multiples of 4. Sort the data in ascending by DoctorID , then count the TotalMedicine the largest, smallest and average on the Doctor ID.

I have tried this

```
SELECT th.TransactionID,
       th.DoctorID,
       th.PatientID,
       COUNT(td.MedicineID) AS TotalMedicine
FROM   TransactionHeader th
       JOIN TransactionDetail td
         ON th.TransactionID = td.TransactionID
WHERE  CAST(RIGHT(th.PatientID, 3) AS INT) % 4 = 0
GROUP  BY th.TransactionID,
          th.DoctorID,
          th.PatientID
ORDER  BY th.DoctorID ASC
COMPUTE max(COUNT(td.MedicineID)), 
        min(COUNT(td.MedicineID)), 
        avg(COUNT(td.MedicineID)) BY th.DoctorID
```

but it didnot select the last 3 digit of the PatientID that are multiplies of 4..

Comment: The last 3 characters of `PA001` as `CHAR(10)` will be three spaces. Why do you need the `PA` prefix anyway. Can't you just use an integer identity column? Also what significance is there to those patients whose id part is divisible by 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you can't change your schema to give `tableHeader` a `varchar` data type, or a `char(5)`,  you need to account for the spaces on the end of the column.

[RTRIM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238471.aspx) will what you want.

```
SELECT th.TransactionID,
       th.DoctorID,
       th.PatientID,
       COUNT(td.MedicineID) AS TotalMedicine
FROM   TransactionHeader th
       JOIN TransactionDetail td
         ON th.TransactionID = td.TransactionID
WHERE  CAST(RIGHT(RTRIM(th.PatientID), 3) AS INT) % 4 = 0
GROUP  BY th.TransactionID,
          th.DoctorID,
          th.PatientID
ORDER  BY th.DoctorID ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `Where Cast(Substring(PatientId, Len(PatientId) - 2, 3) as Integer) % 4 = 0`

```
Select TransactionID, DoctorID, PatientID, 
    Sum() TotalMedicine 
From TransactionHeader th
   JOIN TransactionDetail td
     ON th.TransactionID = td.TransactionID
Where Cast(Substring(PatientId, Len(PatientId) - 2, 3) as Integer) % 4 = 0
GROUP BY th.TransactionID,
      th.DoctorID,th.PatientID
```

Comment: Look at the data schema he posted.